# Rally app settings in multiple mixins

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2

If multiple mixins in the same app try to use settings, will they overwrite each other? In other words can multiple mixins have getSettingsFields?

```
getSettingsFields: function() {
        return [
            {
                field123: 'url',
                xtype: 'rallytextfield'
            }
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the last mixin in will win and replace all the other getSettingsFields methods.  A lot of the time we'll just have one getSettingsField method in the actual app class but delegate the implementation out to a separate class:

https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/board/BoardApp.js#L134

https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/board/Settings.js